# I get an exception while trying to establish connection to ActiveMQ via NMS in .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application, activemq-classic

I am trying to create simple proof of concept console app that produces a XML file message to the queue and then consumes the message from that queue. The problem is that I can't  create a connection via the .CreateConnection() method. When I try to do so I get this exception:

```
Unhandled exception. Apache.NMS.NMSConnectionException: Error creating transport.
 ---> System.Exception: NewInstance failed to find a match for id = tcp
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.TransportFactory.NewInstance(String scheme)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.TransportFactory.CreateTransportFactory(Uri location)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.TransportFactory.CreateTransportFactory(Uri location)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Transport.TransportFactory.CreateTransport(Uri location)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory.CreateActiveMQConnection(String userName, String password)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory.CreateActiveMQConnection()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at ArtemisSender.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\####\Program.cs:line 12
```

Here's my program.cs file:

```
using Apache.NMS;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;

namespace ArtemisSender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(new Uri("activemq:tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"));

            using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                connection.Start();

                using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.AutoAcknowledge))
                {
                    IDestination destination = session.GetQueue("queueAddress:newQueue");

                    using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
                    {
                        ITextMessage textMessage = producer.CreateTextMessage("This is a test message.");

                        producer.Send(textMessage);

                        Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my transportConnectors from the activemq.xml file

```
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

I tried to use different protocols such as stomp but that didn't really help. I've tried disabling firewall and antivirus hoping that maybe this would help but it didn't.

I've looked through the documentation and source code to understand the "failed to find match for id = tcp" message but I didn't find anything on that.

I'm using:
-.NET 7.0
-Apache.NMS v.2.1.0
-Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ v.2.1.0

The Artemis version is 2.31.0

**Found the solution**

The error only occurs on the 2.1.0 version of the Apache.NMS. Moving to the 2.0.0 version solved issue

Comment: Please add more debugging details and what versions of all the libraries you are using, we need details to help and you haven't given us any

Comment: I've updated the post. Tell me if there's anything more i can add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the solution**

The error only occurs on the 2.1.0 version of the Apache.NMS. Moving to the 2.0.0 version solved issue

Answer (score 0):

When using the NMS API factory `NMSConnectionFactory` you need to specify the protocol library you want to use which in your case would be 'activemq' so your URI would look something like

```
activemq:tcp://localhost:61616
```

And you must have a reference to the NMS.ActiveMQ library in your project so that the NMSConnectionFactory can find it. The NMS API alone is not a protocol implementation, you need to get both the API and the client library for the protocol you want to speak.

When using a `ConnectionFactory` from the the protocol library implementation itself an not using the `NMSConnectionFactory` then you shouldn't need to protocol name in the URI like the above but instead should use the standard form, e.g.

```
 tcp://localhost:61616
```

It should be noted that I don't think anyone is actively testing or checking that the NMS client libraries are working on the latest .NET releases.

Comment: I was doing that but it also didn't help. Still got the same exception.
Now I tried switching to artemis. 
So should the uri look like this: "artemis:tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" or should it be the same?

Comment: Nope there is no NMS.Artemis library for the Core protocol, you would need to still use the ActiveMQ one or the AMQP one